# Cannot execute RVM shell commands in ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, rvm

Long time lurker, first time poster!

#### Goal

My ultimate goal is to make a Rake setup script to setup my rvm environment stuff (I need to dynamically create gemsets, install gems to those gemsets, and run ruby scripts within those gemsets).

#### Problem

I need to setup rvm in the shell that I'm executing rvm commands in. The basic idea is to source the rvm scripts [as outlined here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/).

The problem arises when I try and source the rvm script when executing a shell command within ruby. Its well documented that rvm only supports bash, but ruby doesn't seem to be using bash when executing shell commands.

#### What I've Tried

I've tried all the methods to execute shell commands listed [here](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html) to no avail. I'll use the 'exec' method below for simplicity.

It seems that although ruby thinks its using the bash shell to execute these commands ... it is not. Observe!

```
exec 'echo $SHELL'
=> /bin/bash
```

But

```
exec 'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm; type rvm | head -1;'
=> sh: source: not found
=> rvm is ~/.rvm/bin/rvm
```

Which tells me that ruby is really using /bin/sh not /bin/bash (that output should return `rvm is a function`). I even went so far as to print the ruby env stuff, and ENV[SHELL] is '/bin/bash'

#### 'Brute Force' Solution

I do have a workaround, but its really kludgy (this would necessitate that I 'AND' all of the commands together):

```
exec 'echo \'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && type rvm | head -1\' | /bin/bash'
```

I'd like to avoid using shell scripts if possible -- it seems reasonable that I can accomplish this within ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it happens, RVM actually exposes a Ruby API that's included by default. Add `$HOME/.rvm/lib` to your `$LOAD_PATH`; you can now use `require 'rvm'`.

As far as I can tell, the main documentation for this is in the source files themselves (a summary is in `rvm.rb`).

Now you can write Ruby scripts that manipulate RVM, like this:

```
require 'rvm'
env = RVM.current
env.gemset.create('newgemset')
```

And so on.

Comment: Awesome -- thats exactly what I want. Just for curiousity I took a peak at that code -- they're doing something similar conceptually to the 'brute force' method above ... just in a slicker fashion (they use open3 to run the bash shell and send commands to it).

Answer (score 1):

Call bash with the -c parameter:

```
command = 'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm; type rvm | head -1'
exec "bash -c #{command.inspect}"
```

Comment: Does rvm-shell instead of bash replace the source rvm foo?

Comment: Good question, @neonlex. I think so... rvm-shell seems like a good way to go from my experience.